# Python Trailing L Problem

Tags: python

I'm using Python to script some operations on specific locations in memory (32 bit addresses) in an embedded system.

When I'm converting these addresses to and from strings, integers and hex values a trailing L seems to appear.  This can be a real pain, for example the following seemingly harmless code won't work:

```
int(hex(4220963601))
```

Or this:

```
int('0xfb96cb11L',16)
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

So far I've come up with this method to strip the trailing L off of a string, but it doesn't seem very elegant:

```
if longNum[-1] == "L":
   longNum = longNum[:-1]
```

Comment: Your first example wouldn't work even without the "L" because `int` doesn't know how to handle "0x" prefix.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you do the conversion to hex using

```
 "%x" % 4220963601
```

there will be neither the `0x` nor the trailing `L`.

Answer (score 13):

Calling `str()` on those values should omit the trailing 'L'.

Comment: Just to let future readers know, yan's answer of calling 'str' on it doesn't work, at least in Python 2.7.3. Str keeps the trailing 'L'. (I don't have enough reputation to comment on Yan's answer) The answers using format or %x do seem to work.

Comment: broken spacing, but:

Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
    [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> n = 123L
    >>> str(n)
    '123'
    >>> str(123L)
    '123'

Comment: That example is true in general but for hex, hex does not accept strings it returns a string with L in it given an integer :'(

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `rstrip`. For example:

```py
result.rstrip("L")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did: int(variable_which_is_printing_as_123L) and it worked for me. This will work for normal integers.

Answer (score -1):

this could help somebody:

```
>>>n=0xaefa5ba7b32881bf7d18d18e17d3961097548d7cL
>>>print "n=","%0s"%format(n,'x').upper()
n= AEFA5BA7B32881BF7D18D18E17D3961097548D7C
```

Comment: how would this uncommented piece of code help anyone more than the answers given already?