# Tweepy user_id and trailing L

Tags: python, int, long-integer, tweepy

I have a list of followers, I'd like to follow. The one problem that I'm having is that it appears the user_id has to be an int, not a string, and can't have the trailing L. I have some large numbers as id. For example

```
user_id = 900000000000000L
```

I tried changing using a few suggestions like

```
format(user_id, 'd')
```

but it returns a string.

I looked at:

[Python Trailing L Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917203/python-trailing-l-problem)

However hexadecimal isn't an option for me. I understand in C after a certain point an int can't be expressed, and you need a long or double long. however is there a way to override the L in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`900000000000000L` is of type `long` which is an int-like class.  When integers get too big to represent, the automatically convert to long... e.g.:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
>>> sys.maxint + 1
9223372036854775808L
```

Most of the time, `int` and `long` can be used interchangeably and you shouldn't need to worry about it.  However, if having `long` integers really is a problem, for small enough numbers, you can probably just call `int` on it:

```
>>> user_id = 900000000000000L
>>> int(user_id)
900000000000000
```

But if the numbers get bigger than `sys.maxint`, you need to figure out how to make those numbers smaller as it isn't possible to represent them as an `int` any longer<sup>1</sup>...

```
>>> int(sys.maxint + 1)  # still a long.
9223372036854775808L
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>pun intended</sup>

Comment: So basically I'm stuck with using a program for apis that require an int for int large than sys.maxint?

Comment: just adding this comment here for future users. Python 2. has this problem, however I was told it changes in Python 3.

Comment: @user2723240 -- Well ... Sort of.  In python3 there is no difference between `int` and `long`.  However, if your API expects an int in an appropriate range, you still might have troubles...