# Python integers with trailing 'L' in a list

Tags: python, integer, long-integer

I've read some other threads about the Python trailing L problem, such has [Why does python add an 'L' on the end of the result of large exponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741762/why-does-python-add-an-l-on-the-end-of-the-result-of-large-exponents), [Python Trailing L Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917203/python-trailing-l-problem), [Why do integers in database row tuple have an 'L' suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix). But I didn't find an answer that exactly clears up my confusion.

As mentioned here [Why does python add an 'L' on the end of the result of large exponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741762/why-does-python-add-an-l-on-the-end-of-the-result-of-large-exponents), I got the following

```
>>> 25 ** 25
88817841970012523233890533447265625L

>>> str(25**25)
'88817841970012523233890533447265625'
```

so using `str(25**25)` will not show the trailing L, but I also got

```
>>> str([25,25**25])
'[25, 88817841970012523233890533447265625L]'
```

if `str` is applied to a list of numbers the L shows up again, could someone explain why this is so?

What should be a simple way to get the string `[25, 88817841970012523233890533447265625]` from the list `[25,25**25]`?

---

currently what I'm doing is

```
>>> "["+", ".join((map(str, [25,25**25])))+"]"
'[25, 88817841970012523233890533447265625]'
```

Comment: That is because `str(..)` for a list calls `repr(..)` on the **items** of that list.

Comment: You converted the whole list object to a string, so yes, that will include the `repr()` output of the contents. Don't do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks!